# Why does a UIButton have 3 different image properties?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, cocoa-touch, uibutton

A UIButton has 3 different image properties:

currentBackgroundImage
currentImage
imageView

What do each of them represent?

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIButton_Class/UIButton/UIButton.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would say that a `UIButton` has two sets of images:

1. those assigned through: `setImage:forState:`
2. those assigned through `setBackgroundImage:forState:`

They allow you to set foreground and background images for the allowed states to a button: `UIControlStateNormal`, `UIControlStateHighlighted`, `UIControlStateDisabled`, `UIControlStateSelected`, etc. (they are described in the doc you link to, under section "Control State".)

Now, `currentBackgroundImage` and `currentImage` allow direct access to the current image (i.e., the image corresponding to the current state of the button).

On the other hand, `imageView` allows to have access to the `UIImageView` object underlying the button image, so that you can set its properties, if needed. E.g. (from the doc you link):

> Although this property is read-only, its own properties are read/write. Use these properties to configure the appearance and behavior of the button’s view. For example:
>
> ```
>     UIButton *button                   = [UIButton buttonWithType: UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
>     button.imageView.exclusiveTouch    = YES;
> ```

Comment: So why isn't button.imageView simply a UIView object if that is what properties need setting?  I dont' get why it's an imageView and not a UIView.

Comment: A button is composited of perhaps three things: background image, text, label image. The label image (as I just called it) is an image because that's the most common usage pattern. If you really need a button with some arbitrary view as its label, you'll have to create your own.

Comment: UIImageView is subclass of UIView; `imageView` gives you access to the underlying `UIImageView`, for sure. I wrote `UIView` in my answer only because I think that is more usual to need modifying `UIView` properties (unless you would try and have an animated button, e.g.). I will edit my answer to be more precise...